# Fastest way to use Numpy - multi-dimensional sums and products

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have these variables with the following dimensions:

```
A   - (3,)
B   - (4,)
X_r - (3,K,N,nS)
X_u - (4,K,N,nS)
k - (K,)
```

and I want to compute `(A.dot(X_r[:,:,n,s])*B.dot(X_u[:,:,n,s])).dot(k)` for every possible `n` and `s`, the way I am doing it now is the following:

```
np.array([[(A.dot(X_r[:,:,n,s])*B.dot(X_u[:,:,n,s])).dot(k) for n in xrange(N)] for s in xrange(nS)]) #nSxN
```

But this is super slow and I was wondering if there was a better way of doing it but I am not sure.

However there is another computation that I am doing and I am sure it can be optimized:

```
np.sum(np.array([(X_r[:,:,n,s]*B.dot(X_u[:,:,n,s])).dot(k) for n in xrange(N)]),axis=0)
```

In this one I am creating a `numpy` array just to sum it in one axis and discard the array after. If this was a list in 1-D I would use `reduce` and optimize it, what should I use for `numpy` arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using few [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) calls -

```
# Calculation of A.dot(X_r[:,:,n,s])
p1 = np.einsum('i,ijkl->jkl',A,X_r)

# Calculation of B.dot(X_u[:,:,n,s])
p2 = np.einsum('i,ijkl->jkl',B,X_u)

# Include .dot(k) part to get the final output
out = np.einsum('ijk,i->kj',p1*p2,k)
```

About the second example, this solves it:

```
p1 = np.einsum('i,ijkl->jkl',B,X_u)#OUT_DIM - (k,N,nS)
sol = np.einsum('ijkl,j->il',X_r*p1[None,:,:,:],k)#OUT_DIM (3,nS)
```

Comment: @JoãoAbrantes what's p5 in the edits? Should it be p1?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dot` for multiplication of matrices in higher dimensions but the running indices must be the last two.
When we reorder your matrices

```
X_r_t = X_r.transpose(2,3,0,1)
X_u_t = X_u.transpose(2,3,0,1)
```

we obtain for your first expression

```
res1_imp = (A.dot(X_r_t)*B.dot(X_u_t)).dot(k).T # shape nS x N
```

and for the second expression

```
res2_imp = np.sum((X_r_t * B.dot(X_u_t)[:,:,None,:]).dot(k),axis=0)[-1]
```

**Timings**

Divakars solution gives on my computer `10000 loops, best of 3: 21.7 µs per loop`

my solution gives `10000 loops, best of 3: 101 µs per loop`

**Edit**

My upper Timings included the computation of both expressions. When I include only the first expression (as Divakar) I obtain `10000 loops, best of 3: 41 µs per loop` ... which is still slower but closer to his timings

Comment: Appreciate the runtime edits! Good alternative approaches presented in this solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it wasn't the fastest method but it taught me something about numpy that I didn't know and I am sure it will be useful for me in the future! +1